# При запуске приложения на Spring не возвращается содержимое страницы html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Всем привет. Только начинаю разбирать фреймворк Spring и есть вопросы, почему через метод с аннотацией @GetMapping возвращается не название файла.html, а просто строка. Пересмотрел все известные на русском языке видео по этому поводу и все равно не могу понять, что не так. Помогите, пожалуйста. Ссылка на гит: https://github.com/Labazov13/Check.git

```java
package ru.elenaNeMudraya.elenaNeMudraya.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/index.html")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

```java
package ru.elenaNeMudraya.elenaNeMudraya.config;


import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

```java
package ru.elenaNeMudraya.elenaNeMudraya.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.elenaNeMudraya.elenaNeMudraya")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/index/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.elenaNeMudraya</groupId>
    <artifactId>elenaNeMudraya</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>elenaNeMudraya</name>
    <description>Site about a psychology</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HIIII</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>POKAZHIS</p>
</body>
</html>
```

При переходе в браузер (localhost:8080) Вместо содержимого html страницы (POKAZHIS) получаю index

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Не "просто строка", а в любом случае название html-файла. Только без расширения, так как оно задаётся где-нибудь в настройках в качестве суффикса, и без некоторой начальной иерархии папок, которая задаётся в настройках в качестве префикса.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Byb Так в том и дело, что я хочу получить содержимое на этой странице, а мне по итогу возвращается название, которое я задал в return

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте больше конкретной информации. Контроллер, к которому обращаетесь, как обращаетесь, что выдаётся на выходе и так далее. Код прикладывать текстом. "Мне возвращается название" - куда возвращается?) А то пока ничего не понятно

Comment: @Byb отредактировал

Comment: Замените `RestController` на `Controller`. И в `GetMapping` поменяйте `index.html` на `index`.

Comment: @Byb Не помогло. Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Nov 27 23:07:07 GMT+07:00 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @Byb В терминале выводится следующее: 2023-11-27T23:07:04.146+07:00  WARN 12648 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /

Comment: У вас в настройках префикс `/resources/templates/index/` - а `index.html` точно в такой папке хранится или нет? А то более стандартный путь ведь `/resources/templates`. Возможно, `index.html` именно по такому пути хранится

Comment: @Byb Указал templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/"), но все равно не работает. Вывод в браузере: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Nov 28 22:04:59 GMT+07:00 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Ну, тогда уже не могу подсказать. Единственное, что я ещё могу посоветовать (возможно, не поможет в решении проблемы) - убрать все классы-конфиги. Вы используете Spring Boot, а он при наличии соответствующих зависимостей большинство бинов создаёт сам, и вы ими уже просто пользуетесь. Так, например, у вас есть `starter-web` - поэтому класс `SpringMVC` никакой роли не играет. Аналогично добавьте `starter-thymeleaf` - тогда не нужна будет и настройка кучи бинов для Thymeleaf-а.

Comment: А, ну и плюс к этому вы в `Main`-программе указываете, что сканировать нужно только пакет `controller`, но это неправильно. Этот пакет не висит в воздухе, у него есть определённая иерархия. В вашем случае, судя по Гитхабу, это `ru.elenaNeMudraya.controller`. А так получается, что у вас ничего не сканируется.

Comment: @Byb спасибо большое, помогло указание пути ru.elenaNeMudraya.controller в ComponentScan. Извиняюсь, конечно, за отсутствие конкретного вопроса изначально, я только учусь и спасибо за терпение

Comment: Отлично! Рад, что помог